# SQL Server Backup Procedure and different types of backup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Need to know perfect solution on how to backup SQL server Database

Version SQL server 2008 R2.

Comment: "perfect solution". Tell me, what is the BEST CAR? Oh, no requirements - it must be the best in everything? Backup solutions vary widely by requirements. And no, a Q&A forum is not a replacement for doing a little homework yourself. Please head over to dba.stackexchange.com (not serverfault) with this question - once you have a setup you think that works. They (and we) do not take lightly of people disingaging their brain and letting other people do their work - without giving them even the requirements needed to answer.

Comment: The best solution is for someone with an understanding of your needs, most likely to be you, to research the various SQL server backup models, spend some time thinking about which model is most appropriate to your needs, then carefully go about implementing that solution. Once you've done that, by all means ask here for advice if you have any specific issues with implementing or testing your solution... *but **we** can't tell you what you need to do in order to back up **your** data in a manner sufficient to **your** needs and with due consideration of the resources **you** have available.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, there are three the most popular methods to make SQL Server database backup.

1. You can use **T-SQL Commands**:

`BACKUP DATABASE your_database TO DISK = 'full.bak'`

`BACKUP DATABASE your_database TO DISK = 'diff.bak' WITH DIFFERENTIAL`

`BACKUP LOG your_database TO DISK = 'log.bak'`

2. You can use **SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)**. Right-click on the database you want to backup. Select “Tasks”, then “Back up…”. And in the opened window choose “Backup type" and add a backup destination. Click “OK” to start.
3. Or you can use **third-party tools**; You can choose such tool as [SqlBackupAndFtp](http://sqlbackupandftp.com/), or try out [Sqlbak](https://sqlbak.com/) if you prefer SAAS model.

It's a well-known fact that the scheduled backups are the best way to protect your database from the disaster. As for me, the best way to making scheduled database backup is a 3dr party tool. I use the one and really happy. The backups are made according to the schedule and I don't even think about it. I'm sure that if the failure occurs I will be able to restore my database with the minimal loss.